# difference in between npm init -f vs npm init -y

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to know the key difference between npm init -y and in npm init -f as when I write npm init -f or npm init -y, both do the same work of node installation and also in same way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing npm help init prints out helpful information. Namely:

> If you invoke it with -f, --force, -y, or --yes, it will use only
> defaults and not prompt you for any options.

Answer (score 2):

`-f` is shorthand for `-—force`, and `-y` is shorthand for `-—yes`. They both do the same thing, as `—-yes` sets all answers of npm init to defaults, and `—-force` immediately forces the initialization of a node application.